# Search a list based on the input in API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to search a list that I get from GET request based on the parameter that I pass from my TextField controller but the search isn't working, it doesn't display any result and it doesn't show any error either.

Can you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

API request

```
static Future<List<Athlete>> searchAthletesByName(controller, context) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              '$uri/search-athletes-by-name?name=$controller&page=0&length=50'),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ..',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List jsonResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
        return jsonResponse
            .map((_athlete) => Athlete.fromJson(_athlete))
            .toList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e(e.toString());
    }
    return searchAthletesByName(controller, context);
  }
```

The screen where I want to implement the search

```
class _AddAthleteState extends State<AddAthlete> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  Future<List<Athlete>>? futureSearchAthleteByName;
  late List<Athlete> _athlete = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureSearchAthleteByName =
        ApiService.searchAthletesByName(myController, context);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 5),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  controller: myController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
                      future: futureSearchAthleteByName,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          List<Athlete> _athlete = snapshot.data;
                          return ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              cacheExtent: 34,
                              primary: true,
                              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 10,
                                bottom: 56,
                              ),
                              itemCount: _athlete.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                if (myController.text == '') {
                                  return Container();
                                } else if (myController.text != '' &&
                                        _athlete[index]
                                            .lastName
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains(myController.text
                                                .toLowerCase()) ||
                                    _athlete[index]
                                        .firstName
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                        .contains(
                                            myController.text.toLowerCase())) {
                                  return Column(
                                    children: [
                                      ListTile(
                                        title: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '${_athlete[index].lastName} ${_athlete[index].firstName}',
                              });
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
                        }
                        return Container();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the controller object to the api endpoint. You should pass the **controller.text**

```
static Future<List<Athlete>> searchAthletesByName(controller, context) async {
try {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          '$uri/search-athletes-by-name?name=${controller.text}&page=0&length=50'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ..',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    return jsonResponse
        .map((_athlete) => Athlete.fromJson(_athlete))
        .toList();
  }
} catch (e) {
  logger.e(e.toString());
}
return searchAthletesByName(controller, context);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you rely on rebuilding the `FutureBuilder` based on the `TextFormField` widget, use this :

```
     @override
  void initState() {
    futureSearchAthleteByName =
        ApiService.searchAthletesByName(myController, context);
    super.initState();
  }
```

will prevent the `FutureBuilder` to rebuild on any `setState((){})`, so you need to put the `Future` method directly in the future property of the `FutureBuilder`:

```
  FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
   future: ApiService.searchAthletesByName(myController, context),
 /* more code */
```

now when `SetState(() {})` is triggered the `FutureBuilder` will rebuild, in other words, it will send a new request to get a new `snapshot.data` ans show it.

the myController is initialize with no value so the `text` is null, that's why it can throw an error trying to fetch for first time.

you can initialize the controller with an empty text like this :

```
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
```

with this :

```
 TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController(text = "");
```

Here you can notice the second thing, that your passing a `TextEditingController` object which is `myController` inside your method, then you're using that controller in the method directly, which doesn't set the request based on the `String` value of `TextFormField`, you can get it with the `text` property onn the `myController`, so instead of this :

```
 Uri.parse( '$uri/search-athletes-by-name?name=$controller&page=0&length=50'),
```

replace with this :

```
 Uri.parse( '$uri/search-athletes-by-name?name=${controller.text}&page=0&length=50'),
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your  answer. After I did what you suggested as soon as I enter the screen it throws this error before I can even search "FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)". Any idea why?

Comment: can you add this in your initState, print(myController.text); , then give me what it shows in the debug console

Comment: myController.text is null that's why it shows me this error in my api as soon as I enter my screen. But it should't be null if I haven't typed yet? How can I fix it?

Comment: lemme know if this works

Comment: Should I define text before using it? because it gives me error

Comment: yes, inside the initialization of TextEditingController, set the text property to the initial text value, you can set an empty string like this:  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController(text = ""); or replace the "" with the value you want

Comment: Unfortunately it still throws the same error and it's still null